# How to print variable value in next line using echo command

Tags: command-line, bash, printing, echo

I'm getting a curl command output as below

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/harshavardhanc/dockerfile-ansible/pulls\?state\=all | jq -r '.[]|(.number|tostring)+" "+.user.login+" "+.created_at+" "+.merged_at'
```

```
5 test 2019-09-27T11:06:23Z 2019-09-27T11:09:28Z
4 test1 2019-09-26T16:56:40Z 2019-09-26T16:57:02Z
3 test2 2019-09-26T16:54:25Z 2019-09-26T16:54:55Z
2 test3 2019-09-26T16:52:59Z 2019-09-26T16:55:19Z
1 test4 2019-09-26T16:46:52Z 2019-09-26T16:47:25Z
```

and I'm storing it in a variable and trying to pass echo the variable
to pass the value to another command to parse the output. But when I'm trying to echo the variable it is printing all the lines as a single line.

```
prlist=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/harshavardhanc/dockerfile-ansible/pulls\?state\=all | jq -r '.[]|(.number|tostring)+" "+.user.login+" "+.created_at+" "+.merged_at')
echo $prlist
```

```
5 test 2019-09-27T11:06:23Z 2019-09-27T11:09:28Z 4 test1 2019-09-26T16:56:40Z 2019-09-26T16:57:02Z 3 test2 2019-09-26T16:54:25Z 2019-09-26T16:54:55Z 2 test3 2019-09-26T16:52:59Z 2019-09-26T16:55:19Z1 test4 2019-09-26T16:46:52Z 2019-09-26T16:47:25Z
```

How to avoid this printing in different line? Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact commands you are using. We need to see the `curl` command _and_ the `echo` command. You're probably simply not quoting correctly, but you almost certainly don't need to echo at all. If you give us the full commands, we can give you a better solution.

Comment: @terdon I have updated the question with the curl command I'm using.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said before, we need _all_ commands, including the `echo` one. In fact, especially the `echo`. How are you saving the `curl` output in a variable? How are you then printing that variable? And what parsing are you trying to do?

Comment: @dessert  I have updated it

Answer (score 8):

What you describe is the standard behavior of `echo`ing an unquoted variable:

```
$ prlist=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/harshavardhanc/dockerfile-ansible/pulls\?state\=all | 
           jq -r '.[]|(.number|tostring)+" "+.user.login+" "+.created_at+" "+.merged_at')
$ echo $prlist
5 SMYALTAMASH 2019-09-27T11:06:23Z 2019-09-27T11:09:28Z 4 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:56:40Z 2019-09-26T16:57:02Z 3 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:54:25Z 2019-09-26T16:54:55Z 2 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:52:59Z 2019-09-26T16:55:19Z 1 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:46:52Z 2019-09-26T16:47:25Z
```

That's because `$prlist` is not quoted. Compare with what happens if you quote it:

```
$ echo "$prlist"
5 SMYALTAMASH 2019-09-27T11:06:23Z 2019-09-27T11:09:28Z
4 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:56:40Z 2019-09-26T16:57:02Z
3 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:54:25Z 2019-09-26T16:54:55Z
2 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:52:59Z 2019-09-26T16:55:19Z
1 ganesh-28 2019-09-26T16:46:52Z 2019-09-26T16:47:25Z
```

But why use a variable at all? You can just parse the output of `curl` directly:

```
curl ... | jq ... | someOtherCommand
```

Like this:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/harshavardhanc/dockerfile-ansible/pulls\?state\=all | 
  jq -r '.[]|(.number|tostring)+" \
    "+.user.login+" "+.created_at+" "+.merged_at'curl \
    -s https://api.github.com/repos/harshavardhanc/dockerfile-ansible/pulls\?state\=all |
 someOtherCommand
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon, adding quotes worked.

Comment: I'm storing it in a variable because I need to pass same output as input to multiple api's down the script. @terdon